# How to delete all items in list one by one and printing them simultaneously after deleting

Tags: python

I am trying to delete elements of a list one by one, and i want to print each element after deleting in the same for loop.

I've tried to delete them using the following code but it says
'IndexError: list assignment index out of range'

```py
usernames = ['yasir', 'anjum', 'moin', 'admin', 'iqbal'] 
if usernames:
    for i in range(0, len(usernames)):
        #print (usernames[i]) this is working fine
        del (usernames[i])
else:
    print('The list is already empty')
```

I'm expecting to print the element after deleting it till I'm done deleting all the elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using a fixed loop from `0..N-1` with `N` only calculated once, i.e. when you first enter the loop. But due to the `del()` `N` (== `len(username)`) decreases with every trip around the loop. At some point you reach `i >= N` and hence `IndexError: list index out of range`.

Try this variant instead:

```python
while usernames:
    print(usernames[0])
    del(usernames[0])
```

Comment: They key point here is that `del` changes your list (makes it shorter) while inside the loop.

Answer (score 2):

Use `list.pop` method.

```
>>> usernames = ['yasir', 'anjum', 'moin', 'admin', 'iqbal'] 
>>> 
>>> while usernames:
...     print (usernames.pop())
... 
iqbal
admin
moin
anjum
yasir
```

Reverse the list, if you like to retain order.

Answer (score 0):

The `del` statement causes all the later elements to move to the left in the list.  This is why you're getting the `IndexError`—by the time your loop gets about halfway through the list, the list isn't long enough anymore!

You can delete each element, one at a time, using

```
while usernames:
    del usernames[0]
```

If you need to output each element *after* you delete it, you'll have to keep it in a variable first.

```
while usernames:
    name = usernames[0]
    del usernames[0]
    print(name)
```

Note that deleting from a list is a bit inefficient, because the rest of the elements in the list have to be renumbered.

Answer (score 0):

This is using for loop, not as efficient but works.

```
usernames = ['yasir', 'anjum', 'moin', 'admin', 'iqbal'] 
for i in range(len(usernames)):
    print(usernames[0])
    del usernames[0]
```